# Find and replace by AWK

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file named sfe_mail.txt which has a content of

```
Katia   Dargains
Artur   Santos
Marcio  Breder
Luis    Plum
Michel  Aguiar
Vinicius    Lourenco
Willian Wendling
Paulo   Araujo
```

I want to replace spaces and tabs in between words by a dot.

I have issued the command:

```
awk '{ gsub (/  \t+/,".");print}' sfe_mail.txt
```

But its not working.Can you tell whats wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tabs and spaces are the default field separator in awk. Set the output field separator to `.`, rebuild the record with `$1=$1` and output:

```
$ awk -v OFS="." '{$1=$1;print}' file
Katia.Dargains
Artur.Santos
Marcio.Breder
Luis.Plum
Michel.Aguiar
Vinicius.Lourenco
Willian.Wendling
Paulo.Araujo
```

If you insist on using `gsub`:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/[\t ]+/,".");print}' file
```

Your matching regex was `/  \t+/` ie. 2 spaces and one or more tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Simple ***sed*** alternative:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/./' file
```

---

As for *awk*, the one below would be the simplest for your case:

```
awk '{ print $1"."$2 }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

simple solution using awk

```
awk '{ print $1"."$2 }' sfe_mail.txt
```

You can also try **tr** as @James suggested in comment

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' . < sfe_mail.txt
```